# What is the earliest time we might be reasonably sure who won the US 2020 Presidential election?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, presidential-election, joe-biden

With all the absentee votes and the different rules in different states (and counties!), I find it hard to say at which time we can expect the result of which state.

If Trump wins the election it will probably be a tight race and it will take time to make sure this is really the case.

If Biden wins, he might already have won before all the states have finished counting.

What would be a good estimate for the earliest time at which Biden might have won the election?

Comment: Any "good estimate" should be based on multiple prior experiences. What is happening now is virtually unprecedented. The flu epidemic in 1918, to my knowledge, did not have this level of mail-in ballots, if any. VTC speculation.

Comment: I reworded the title because the question was collecting downvotes and close votes. The title was assuming who would win, while the body was not.

Comment: [This BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/election-us-2020-54723228) has some mention of important times on election night.

Comment: A politics professor on the news stated "up to five days after the election"

Comment: Who wins may be decided in courts after multiple cases as it seems Trump has threatened to contest a vote he does not win.  That could take a long time to sort out.  I would say it is even possible we may not know until a president is sworn in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a tricky question and depends on the definition of "reasonable knowledge" or "good estimate".

There are a range of possible scenarios in some of which we won't know the winner for weeks.

But since you're specifically asking about the *earliest possible moment*, it would probably be when Florida reports its first results and they show Biden performing as strongly or better than in current polls. In a recent [Reddit AMA](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/jjr0wk/im_elliott_morris_a_data_journalist_at_the/), election forecaster Elliott Morris said that Trump's chances of winning the election are essentially 0 should he lose in Florida:

> *If you could only follow one state on election night, and we’re
> completely blind to any info about the others, which would it be?*
>
> Florida — if Trump loses, he has a 0% chance to win, according to our model.

This is because the current polls show Florida to be tighter than other major swing states like Pennsylvania or Michigan. In other words, if early results from Florida were to point to a Biden landslide in the state, Trump would likely also lose the other swing states.

Note that this doesn't mean that you can simply look at the first 5 or 10 or even 30% of votes counted in Florida and assume that the person who is leading at that point will go on to win the state. Rather, you would want to look at the demographic characteristics of the first areas reporting results (rural, urban, young, old, ...) and factor those in when you make a guess about who will win the state as a whole.

Compared to other swing states, Florida's vote count operation is very efficient. If Biden were to dominate there, news organisations could 'call' the state for him within 1-2 hours of the last polls closing there, which they do at 8pm Eastern Time.

If this were to happen, we still couldn't assume Biden to become the overall winner *with absolute certainty* of course, but at that point a Trump comeback would be incredibly unlikely.

Comment: Of course, [Florida was called for Gore a little before 8 PM on Election Night 2000,](https://uselectionatlas.org/INFORMATION/ARTICLES/ElectionNight/pe2000elecnighttime.php) and we all know how that turned out.  News organizations are presumably more careful with their calls now, and I wouldn't be surprised if they're extra-cautious with Florida.

Comment: FiveThirthyEight (another election forecaster) as an online tool to do predictions like the one you mention. I have no idea how reliable the underlying model is, but it is definitely fun to play with. Link: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/trump-biden-election-map/

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Even though it was called, it was close. That's why the answer says it would have to be a landslide.